# How to git merge, but not using the latest commit

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a `master` branch and a `develop` branch.  The `develop` branch has moved ahead of the `master` by about 10 commits, but the version approved by the client included only the first 8 commits.

How do I merge only the first 8 commits from `develop` into `master`?

Normally I would do this:

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
```

But obviously that would merge in all of the `develop` commits.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may merge via SHA-1 commit hash, e.g.

```
git checkout master
git merge 3JH9sdx8
```

Where `3JH9sdx8` is the commit hash of `develop` from two commits prior to the HEAD of the branch.  To find that `3JH9sdx8` hash, you could use `git log develop` and check.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a branch 2 version back

```
git checkout dev
git checkout -b devapproved @~2
```

Then you can merge that branch

```
git checkout master
git merge devapproved
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cherry-pick` command.

First `git log` command give you the hash of the previous commits and then you can use the `git cherry-pick [yourHashString]` command in order to merge the specified commit to the current branch.

Answer (score 1):

you could get the merge's version and  create temporary branch ,for example:

```
# find the commit id
git log --oneline 

# checkout new branch by commit id 
git checkout commitID  -b tmp

# Switched to branch 'master'
git checkout master

git merge tmp

# delete branch
git branch -d tmp
```